# Multiple sheet copying from a working sheet to an archive sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

I have had some help with the last line of this code and it works perfectly for a single sheet in the spreadsheet, however I have 5 sheets in the From spreadsheet and identical 5 sheets in the target spreadsheet how can I get the same range in the other 4 sheets to their same named counterpart in the target sheet? So I used below to try and copy each sheet to its corresponding namesake but I have set up the code as below but only importing the first sheet, also is there a way to only need to enter the originating spreadsheet id once for the whole code instead of at each sheet section?

```
 function ImportDataRange() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Z0zU2oGktLPB-QitYMm9XtOGN4Rd-Z-UJJomGX4NIO0'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('AM trip'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PM trip'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Z0zU2oGktLPB-QitYMm9XtOGN4Rd-Z-UJJomGX4NIO0'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('PM trip'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pool / Beach'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Z0zU2oGktLPB-QitYMm9XtOGN4Rd-Z-UJJomGX4NIO0'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('Pool / Beach'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Night Dive'); //To Sheet Name
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Z0zU2oGktLPB-QitYMm9XtOGN4Rd-Z-UJJomGX4NIO0'); // From Spreadsheet ID
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('Night Dive'); // From Sheet name
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('B7:U38');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
 sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

Thank you for any help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be simplified using a loop.

You said above that you have 5 sheets but you only have 4 in the code sample, add the other sheet name to `var sheetNames`.

```
function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.createMenu('Backup to archive')
    .addItem('Backup', 'dataBackup')
    .addToUi();
}

function dataBackup() {

    var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wglM4-5jx873vwtFRPVgC1qk27JjrsYjDwp0fNpl5Xg'); // The file ID of the Input sheet
    var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g'); // The file ID of the archive sheet

    // The names of the sheets to be copied.
    // NOTE: These names must match the names of the sheets in BOTH spreadsheets i.e. the same case the spelling and the same spaces.
    var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];

    for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) { // Loop to each sheet listed in 'var sheetNames' and copy the data.

        var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
        var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

        var data = inputSheet.getRange('B7:U38').getValues();

        archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tidying it up. I changed a couple of things so only 4 pages now, as listed. I run the script but only the first page AM Trip copies, none of the other pages copy and they all have data on as I have pasted some in to check.  Also can you explain or point me to the place that explains the line "var i = 0......"  Thanks I have tried searching but can't find an explanation only many examples of it.

Comment: @Paul, not sure why the script is not working. I suspect it may be the sheet names do not match? have a look at these 2 sheets. The Input sheet contains the script and a custom menu to call it. [Input sheet](http://gg.gg/4iork) and [Archive sheet](http://gg.gg/4iorj). `var i = 0` is a counter for the  for loop  [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). IMO, this script is less than ideal for what you need. Contact me: jamesd at nairongschool.com