# use a script to import a data range using a menu button

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

I have been working on a project to transfer our daily records from 4 sheets in a spreadsheet to a master copy at the end of each day.  I initially started with the master copy grabbing a copy but timed triggers became a headache so I then wanted to add a menu button to each daily sheet called "End of Day" so that when they had finished at close of business they pushed the button and it went out to the master sheet.  So I got the menu item (as well as a 2nd one to check i knew what I was doing) then added the script into the first menu item but it doesn't seem to work properly.  The sheet names are in the same order and named the same in both spreadsheets although I want the new range to be pasted in the 2nd column as I have a datestamp auto entered in the 1st column.  I don't (at the moment need a sub header which is why I have // it out)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('End of Day')
          .addItem('Robins EOD', 'menuItem1')
          .addItem('Huh', menuItem2)
         // .addSeparator()
         // .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
         // .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
          .addToUi();
    }

    function menuItem1() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var targSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mHYT-_4VV89MEp5Bn9wQi4hCI_JZjN5XlZuqa2iDt8k');

      var sheetNames = ['AM trip','PM trip','Pool / Beach','Night Dive'];

      for(var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i ++){

        var scrSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
        var targSheet = targSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

        var data = scrSheet.getRange('A7:U38').getValues();

        targSheet.getRange(targSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2 , data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

    }
}

    function menuItem2() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
         .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work properly?What excatly happens when you run the above code? Also, you have the second function `menuItem2()` within the first funciton `menuitem1()`. (Look for where you open the curly braces and where you close the curly braces)

Comment: Sorry updated original code with curly braces in correct place, the script is now running but not all the information is being copied across.  All I am getting is the first column copied across but none of the others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple sheet copying from a working sheet to an archive sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598665/multiple-sheet-copying-from-a-working-sheet-to-an-archive-sheet)